# Слетел перевод подсказки при фильтрации по метке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

На странице меток отсутствует перевод подсказки в блоке фильтрации:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевел как:

> Фильтрация по имени метки

Будет на сайте после подгрузки Transifex и пересборки движка.

P.S. Слово «метки» пришлось убрать в конце, т.к. фраза не помещалась в поле ввода. По контексту метка тут подразумевается.